# LeafLet Ribbon Path Between Two Custom Markers

Tags: leaflet

I have a map with two custom marker icons. One is a starting point and the other is the destination.
I can add a route between the two points but it adds A and B letters to the end.
Can I tell the marker plugin to not render the AB letters?
If not then what do I need to do to build the path between the two customer icons?

The code below maps the two points but includes the AB endpoints. Is there an option to exclude the endpoints?

```
dir = MQ.routing.directions();

                dir.route({
                    locations: [
                        { latLng: { lat: startlat, lng: startlong} },
                        { latLng: { lat:endlat , lng: endlong } }
                    ]
                });



                map.addLayer(MQ.routing.routeLayer({
                    directions: dir,
                    draggable: false,
                    fitBounds: true
                }));
```

Comment: Leaflet doesn't support routing out of the box so it would be nice if you add what library/plugin you're using and how you've implemented it in code.

Comment: I updated the question. I use MapQuest. MQ.routing.routeLayer

Answer (score 0):

you could use CSS to hide the markers. For example if the marker icon URL included `text=A` you could use;

`#dragMapWindow img[src*="text=A"] { 
    visibility:hidden; 
}`

the above tests out ok on the drag route example @ http://mapquestapi.com/directions